# Why doesn't bash recognize the case option with a hyphen/dash?

Tags: bash, sh

I'm trying to use a `case` statement to determine if I have a legal command. It looks something like this:

```
function commandTest {
    case $1 in
    –score) echo "something";;
    *)      echo "unknown";;
    esac
}
```

Now if I use the function like this, it doesn't work, because `case` doesn't recognize the string correctly although it is identical.

```
$ commandTest "-score"
unknown
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You're not using the proper hyphen in `–score)` it should be `-score`.

Answer (score 7):

As posted, your sample code has an [en-dash](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2013/index.htm) (Unicode U+2013) in front of `score`, instead of a minus sign (ASCII 0x2D), which is preventing bash from matching the string `-score`

Switch:

```
–score) echo "something"
```

to:

```
-score) echo "something"
```

Comment: I'm sorry, what's an em-dash?

Comment: Turns out it was an "en-dash", not an "em-dash".  Both are typographic characters a bit longer than a minus/dash sign, and to a human look visually very similar to a dash, but very different to the bash shell.  They are difficult to enter with standard text editors.  If you used something like MS word to draft your code, switch to a standard text editor, like vim, emacs, or notepad++

Comment: Hmm, I don't know how it got there then, but just replace it with a minus sign, and your case statement should work.

Comment: can it be because I did copy-paste from a pdf file?

Comment: Yes, that could do it if whoever/whatever generated the PDF accidentally inserted an en-dash instead of dash.